# Difference sorting & separating

Tags: meaning, differences

Is there a difference between sortation and separation?

Comment: (1) there is no word _sortation_. (2) _Separate_ can apply to two or more items, and simply means causing them not to be together. After buying groceries, one could separate the purchases by laying them out on a table. (3) _Sort_ means to separate **and** to place into groups according to some category system. One can sort groceries by putting all the vegetables in one group, all the dairy in another, and so on. Online one can sort items in a folder by some category -- sort by price, sort by date, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Sortation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sortation) refers to [the process of sorting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sortation).** 
**[Separation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/separation) refers to [the process of separating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/separation).**

So, let's reveal the difference between Sorting and Separating.

**[Separating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/separate)** (verb) means dividing a particular object into constituent or distinct elements. Both separating and sorting apply to living creatures like humans (*eg:* *separating some people from a group of people*). But the main point to be considered here is that **separating doesn't specifies any basis of diving the objects, it can be random or on the basis of types.**

While,

**[Sorting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sorting)** (verb) **is a type of separation where the objects are divided on the basis of any characteristic in common.** (*eg: Dividing people on the basis of age or race from a group of people*)

> Therefore, Sorting is a type of separation where objects are divided
>   on the basis of kind, class, or nature (i.e. **sorting = classified separation**)

*Hope, it helped :)*